Tail Probability Expectation Formula
On page one of the following paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.10985
The following calculation is made:
$K \in R^+$ is a threshold
f(.) density function for random variable $X \in R^+$
$P_K = P(X>K) \in [0,1]$ the probability of exceeding it
$g(x): R^+ \rightarrow R$ an impact function
$G_K = \int_K^{\infty} g(x)f(x)dx (1)$
The complimentary CDF function at K:
$P_K = \int_K^{\infty} f(x) dx(2)$
The error comes from conflating the properties of GK which
those of PK, often associating PK with some constant representing the presumed impact associated with the threshold K
The intuition of the difference can be shown as follows:
assuming g(x) = x, for X a random variable with finite
first moment, we have, focusing on the positive domain,
generalizing the Tail Probability Expectation Formula,
$G_K = KP_K + \int_K^{\infty} P_x dx$
The first term is straightforward application of equation 1 with $g(x)=x$ at the start of the integral, is this correct?
I am confused as to why x does not appear in the second term, can someone please explain?
$G_K = \int_K^{\infty} xf(x)dx$ $\neq$ $\int_K^{\infty} f(x) dx$ $=$ $\int_K^{\infty} P_x dx$

Perhaps you can edit your question to make it more clear. Examples: (i) "The error comes from conflating..."  (the error of what?); (ii) "The intuition of the difference..." (the difference of what? What are you talking about?); (iii) "The following calcuation is made" (but then you give only definitions with no calculation).
